# C# Sockets MemoryStream

Tags: c#, sockets, byte, memorystream

So I'm trying to call a method which converts a integer into 4 bytes,

The conversion is written like this -

```
    public void put4(int var1)
    {
        this.payload[++this.offset - 1] = (byte)(var1 >> 24);
        this.payload[++this.offset - 1] = (byte)(var1 >> 16);
        this.payload[++this.offset - 1] = (byte)(var1 >> 8);
        this.payload[++this.offset - 1] = (byte)var1;
    }
```

Which puts

```
var1
```

into 4 bytes

but how could I use this with memorystream?

I know I can send a singlebyte with

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

  ms.WriteByte(1);
```

but I want to send "1" in 4 bytes

what I have tried is,

```
 ms.WriteByte.put4(1);
```

I'm very confused to be honest with you, as I'm not familiar with networking or bytes, but what I do know is, that this specific integer needs to be sent in 4 bytes not as a single byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this, i.e you could use the [`BinaryWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) class

However, to answer your question in regards to a `MemoryStream`

[BitConvert.GetBytes(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Int32_)

> Returns the specified 32-bit signed integer value as an array of
>   bytes.

```
var bytes = BitConvert.GetBytes(someInt);

stream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
```

<sub>***Note*** : You have to be-careful about the platform you are using, and the endianness</sub>

Comment: bytes.length is the maximum number of bytes to write? so if I was to do

Stream.write(bytes,0,4) it would write 4 bytes?

Comment: yes it would write 4 bytes, which is what bitconverter converts it to